# Flex Video Player fullscreenButton override

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex-spark

I'm using mxml to create a spark video player with controls. When I click on the "fullscreen" button in Chrome, it goes full screen on the browser but I am unable to go back to normal size. In Internet Explorer, the whole screen is filled up but the zoom on the video is too big and thus my controls are no longer visible.

Is there any way that I can use ActionScript to control the size of the fullscreen? How would convert the mxml to Actionscript to override this?

Thanks!

Source code from: [Flex Video Player](http://insideria.com/2009/05/wow-video-in-flex-4-is-easy.html)

The code I'm using to create the player:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<s:VideoPlayer 
    source="video.flv"
    horizontalCenter="0"
    verticalCenter="0"
    autoPlay="false" />
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to constrain the area for fullscreen display using stage's [fullScreenSourceRect](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#fullScreenSourceRect) property.